# 10 numbers - combined two different numbers

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Before I ask my question let me say I did search for this problem, but I don't have a clue how this would be called - so I'm sorry if this was asked/answered before!

For an audit I have multiple (10) numbers, to make it easy lets say these numbers:

2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20.

On the other hand I have 2 numbers, that are a sum of the previous numbers - I don't know which numbers and how many numbers would add up to the two numbers. It could be 8&2 numbers or 5&5 numbers..

Is there a simple tool or something to find out which numbers belong to which one? With these numbers I would have multiple combinations that lead to an answer - but how would someone calculate this? Does this have a (mathematical) name?

2 numbers:
50 & 60

eg:
2+6+10+14+18 = 50 & 4+8+12+16+20 = 60
20+18+12 = 50 & 2+4+6+8+10+14+16 = 60
etc

Hope you understand my question/problem ;)
Thanks for any advice

P.s. I didn't know which tag to use.

Comment: there is no unique way to represent a number using this method, for example $20+18+10+2=50$ or $14+16+20=50$

Comment: Perhaps if you elaborate on what you mean by "For an audit," we can help identify the underlying mathematical problem you're looking for. As is, the question is unclear (at least to me). Based on the example, it looks like you're asking how many ways can you partition a given set of (ten) numbers into two disjoint sets, each with a specified sum ($50$ and $60$ in the example), and you'd especially like it if there were only *one* way to do so. Of course the two specified sums have to add up to the total sum of the given (ten) numbers, so this is mathematically equivalent...

Comment: ...to asking how many subsets of the given numbers have just one of the two specified sums (say $50$).

Answer (score 1):

Let's call your $2$ numbers as $x$ and $y$.

From what I understand, of your $10$ other numbers, some subset of them sum to $x$, and the remaining numbers (from your set of $10$) sum to $y$. In this case, it's sufficient for us to find the subset of the $10$ numbers that adds to $x$, because the remaining numbers in our set of $10$ that aren't in this subset will surely sum to $y$.

Our question now becomes, in a set of numbers, how can I find the subset that sum to a certain value ($x$). After looking around a bit on how to do this, I found a post in StackOverflow relating to this "0-1 Knapsack problem". Following those steps, you can find the subset of your $10$ numbers that add to $x$, and the remaining numbers in your set of $10$ will sum to $y$.

Link to StackOverflow question covering how to solve "0-1 Knapsack" problems in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420937/algorithm-to-find-which-number-in-a-list-sum-up-to-a-certain-number

Edit: Since you're only dealing with a set of $10$ numbers, it would probably be much easier and sufficiently fast to just brute force it to find which subset sums to $x$. For generating the subsets, you can use the itertools package in Python and loop over r from 1 to 10 (number of elements in the subset), and append them all into a list. Then you can simply go through the list and check each subset to see if the sum equals $x$. Since you only have $10$ numbers, there's only $2^{10} = 1024$ possible subsets, and recent computers can process that in seconds.